# How do I specify multiple (but not all) drives for an osx Smart Folder to search?

Tags: macos, finder

When I create a new Smart Folder I can either set it to "This Mac" which searches all my drives (including ones I don't want like my backup drive), or to one location like my Macontosh HD root folder. But I want to create a Smart Folder that searches my Internal drive AND Media/External drive but NOT my Backup drive. How do I specify this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create a Smart Folder to search multiple folders, you have to do some of the work manually.

Decide exactly which folders you want to search. Select one of those folders in Finder, and create a Smart Folder and for "Search:"  use the  specific folder you selected, **not** "This Mac". Add the other search criteria you require as normal, e.g. file types etc. Then save the smart folder. In the Finder window make sure  the newly created Smart Folder is **not** selected.

Open  another Finder window and goto ~Library/Saved Searches. Locate the search you just saved above, and *drag* it from the Finder to a text editor, e.g. TextEdit, or TextWrangler.

Now search in the editor for *FXScopeArrayOfPaths*

You should see something like:-

```
<key>FXScopeArrayOfPaths</key>
    <array>
      <string>/the Path you entered for your SmartFolder</string>          
    </array>
```

For each additional folder (i.e. path)you want to search  add an additional line with its path beginning with `<string>` and ending with `</string>`

e.g.

```
<key>FXScopeArrayOfPaths</key>
   <array>
     <string>/the Path you entered for your SmartFolder</string>
     <string>/Users/fred/Documents</string>
     <string>/Users/shared</string>     
   </array>
```

Save this file.
From the Apple menu select Force Quit and relaunch Finder.
Your Smart Folder should now work across all the folders you selected.

I have verified that all of the above works in Yosemite, 10.10.3.

I don't think you can simply add the entire Macintosh HD as a path, since that would presumably include /Volumes which would then pull in your attached drives. The safe way is just to add in the directories you need e.g. /Users, /Volumes/my backup drive, etc.

Comment: Works perfectly, should be marked as answer. Except instruction path has a slight issue, it's "~/Library/Saved Searches" if you use Finder's Go to Location. I used this to filter out documents from my code repository and only see my own docs.